# Trouble to pass Iron handlers with closure in the router declaration

Tags: mongodb, rust, iron

I'm trying to declare my routes with closures:

```
use mongodb::Client;

pub fn get_user_routes(client: Client) -> Router {
    let controller = controller::UserController::new(client);
    let handler = handlers::UserHandler::new(controller);

    router!(
         index:  get    "/"    => move |r: &mut Request| handler.index(r),
         show:   get    "/:id" => move |r: &mut Request| handler.show(r),
    )
}
```

I get this error and I can't implement the `Copy` trait for my `UserController` because the [`mongodb::Client`](https://docs.rs/mongodb/0.2.3/mongodb/type.Client.html) doesn't implement it (it's an `Arc`).

```
error[E0382]: capture of moved value: `handler`
      --> src/api/users/mod.rs:17:57
       |
    16 |         index:  get    "/"    => move |r: &mut Request| handler.index(r),
       |                                  ---------------------- value moved (into closure) here
    17 |         show:   get    "/:id" => move |r: &mut Request| handler.show(r),
       |                                                         ^^^^^^^ value captured here after move
       |
       = note: move occurs because `handler` has type `api::users::handlers::UserHandler`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

My `UserHandler` just has a `UserController` and the `UserController`, a `mongodb::Client`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The router `get` method takes a handler by *value*. In Rust, passing by value implies giving up ownership.

By definition, you cannot give up ownership of something twice: it's no longer yours after you gave it up the first time! The only exception to the rule is `Copy` types, but those are restricted to things like integers and non-mutating references (and references are out because `Handler: 'static`).

Thus, you *need* to call `.clone()` on the handler to be passed. Every time.

A very simple way is to use a block-expression:

```
let h  = handler;
router!(
    index: get "/"    => { let h = h.clone(); move |r: &mut Request| h.index(r) },
    show:  get "/:id" => { let h = h.clone(); move |r: &mut Request| h.show(r) },
)
```

this way, you do not have to declare all the clones beforehand.

Answer (score 1):

You can `#[derive(Clone)]` for your handler, and clone it:

```
let handler_show = handler.clone();
router!(
     index:  get    "/"    => move |r: &mut Request| handler.index(r),
     show:   get    "/:id" => move |r: &mut Request| handler_show.show(r),
)
```

Comment: Thank for the response, but unfortunately i'll have more than 2 routes in the future and i think it's not a elegant solution to create a variable for each new routes.